# Anyone have a way to plot a bean plot in gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, data-visualization

Title is pretty self explanatory but here is a picture of what I'd like to do. I'm having a tough time figuring out if its even possible.

[image: example bean plot]

Plot borrowed from:
*Evaluation of geochemical background levels around sulfide mines – A new statistical procedure with beanplots. Gusstavason et al. 2012.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing the plot in exactly this orientation could be very cumbersome, if possible at all.

My suggestion is to plot everything with the usual orientation (i.e. having the 'sediments' axis as `x`-axis, or rather as `x2`-axis), rotate all labels a bit and finally rotate the complete output by `90` degree (pdf file with e.g. `pdftk` etc).

With this you can use any plot style as usual. In the script below I just show you how to plot the violet and yellow filled curves (using pseudo data) for two different data sets. Adding the other peaks should be straight forward (plot the bars with e.g. `boxes` or `vector` plotting style).

In order to have distinct `ytics` for the different plots, I associated a certain `y`-value with a certain plot, `1=Water`, ..., `4=Gyttja`).

Putting all toghether gives the following script:

```
reset
set terminal pdfcairo linewidth 2
outfile='bean'
set output outfile.'.pdf'
set encoding utf8

set x2range [0.5:9000]
set logscale x2
set x2tics (1, 5, 10, 50, '' 100, 500, '' 1000, 5000) out
set x2label 'mg/kg (sediments), µg/L (water)'
unset xtics

set yrange[0.5:4.5]
set ytics ('Water' 1, 'Minerogenic' 2, 'Peat' 3, 'Gyttja' 4) center rotate by -90 out

set label at graph 0.95, graph 0.05 right rotate by -90 'Nickel' font ',20' front
# cover possible data overlapping with the label
set object rectangle from graph 0.9, graph 0 to graph 1,graph 0.2 fillcolor rgb 'white' fillstyle solid noborder front

unset key

set macros
fs1="fillcolor rgb '#fc9e00' linewidth 2 fillstyle solid border lt -1"
fs2="fillcolor rgb '#9119f7' linewidth 2 fillstyle solid border lt -1"
# use pseudo data
set samples 500
plot '+' using 1:(4-0.3*exp(-(($1-10)/5.0)**4)) axes x2y1 with filledcurves y1=4 @fs1,\
     '' using 1:(4+0.2*exp(-(($1-70)/50.0)**4)) axes x2y1 with filledcurves y1=4 @fs2,\
     '' using 1:(1-0.4*exp(-(($1-5)/2.0)**2)) axes x2y1 with filledcurves y1=1 @fs1,\
     '' using 1:(1+0.1*exp(-(($1-30)/20.0)**2)) axes x2y1 with filledcurves y1=1 @fs2

set output
system(sprintf('pdftk %s.pdf cat 1W output %s-rot.pdf', outfile, outfile))
system(sprintf('pdftocairo -r 150 -png %s-rot.pdf', outfile))
```

This gives (conventional and rotated output side-by-side) with 4.6.3:

[image]

Some stuff is required for the pseudo data. For a real data file, the plotting line looks a bit differently. The different plots have a separation of `1` in `y`-direction, so you must scale your data accordingly (done here manually with a scaling factor `sc`):

```
sc = 5.1
plot 'datafile.txt' using 1:(4 + $2/sc) axes x2y1 with filledcurves y1=4 @fs1
```

You can of course also do the scaling automatically, by extracting some minimum/maximum values using the `stats` command.

Comment: Thank you so much for a starting point. And the orientation isn't an issue , I just need to display multiple distributions next to each other so they can be compared.